Memory efficient way of calculating N-body-like problem or how to iterate over a list
There is 1D List of numerical data (let's call it positions). I would like to update it using a special function f folded on the whole array for each element similar to a typical N-body problem.
My naive solution
positions = RandomReal[{-1,1}, {200,2}];

f = Function[{x1, y1, x2, y2}, 
    With[{a = 0.398 * E^(-0.5 * ((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2))}, 
            {a * (x1 - x2), a * (y1 - y2)}
        ]
];

positions = Map[Function[p,

  p + 0.01 Sum[f[p[[1]], p[[2]], h[[1]], h[[2]]], {h, positions}]

], positions]; // AbsoluteTiming // First 

0.186

Using Table
(positions = positions +  0.01 Map[Total] @ Table[
  
  f[p[[1]], p[[2]], h[[1]], h[[2]]], 
  
{h, positions}, {p, positions}]); // AbsoluteTiming // First 

0.185

Then I have found one trick: if we scope positions inside a function, it gives a large boost due to vectorization (?)
(positions = Function[positions, positions +  0.01 Map[Total] @ Table[
  
  f[p[[1]], p[[2]], h[[1]], h[[2]]], 
  
{h, positions}, {p, positions}]][positions]); // AbsoluteTiming // First 

0.00702

However, if I try it on a more memory efficient implementation
(positions = Function[positions, Map[Function[p,

  p + 0.01 Sum[f[p[[1]], p[[2]], h[[1]], h[[2]]], {h, positions}]

], positions]][positions]); // AbsoluteTiming // First 

0.182

it does not work.
Then it raises a question.
Is there any way of folding list on itself like in N-body problem without quadratic memory consumption?
Thanks
PS: I am aware of Compile expression, however, it would be nice to still keep the code within a traditional WL style

"Is there any way of folding list on itself like in N-body problem without quadratic memory consumption?" Yes, there way to go for general interaction kernels is to use some kind of tree code like the Barnes-Hut Method or the Fast Multipole Method. If it is literally a discrete convolution, then methods based on the Fast Fourier Transform are easier and faster. I think ListConvolve might be able to do that. Each of these has storage and time complexity at most $O(n \log(n))$.

I'm seeing two different results (first and last implementations agree, middle two agree). Which one is the correct expected result?
